# Using lists in R

Tags: r

Sorry for possibly a complete noob question but I have just started programming with R today and I am stuck already.

I am reading some data from a file which is in the format.

```
3.482373 8.0093238198371388 47.393873
0.32 20.3131 31.313
```

What I want to do is split each line then deal with each of the individual numbers.

I have imported the stringr package and using

```
x = str_split(line, " ")
```

This produces a list which I would like to index but don't know how.

I have learnt that x[[1:2]] gets the second element but that is about it. Ideally I would like something like

```
x1 = x[1]
x2 = x[2]
x3 = x[3]
```

But can't find anyway of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would read the help page you get by typing ?Extract at the console, if you're just getting started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have looked at both help(list) and help(str_split) but still can't make sense of it.

Comment: My intent was that you'd learn things like the fact that `[[` only ever selects one element, so using it with a vector if indices doesn't do much. In particular, with lists, `[` and `[[` have very different behavior that important to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your call to `str_split` with `unlist` to get the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

By using `unlist` you will get a vector instead of a list of vectors, and you will then be able to index it directly :

```
R> unlist(str_split("foo bar baz", " "))
[1] "foo" "bar" "baz"
```

But maybe you should read your file directly from read.table or one of its variant ?

And if you are beginning with R, you really should read one of the introduction available if you want to understand subsetting, indexing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to get this in would be to import it into a dataframe (a special sort of list). If file name is "fil.dat"" and is in "C:/dir/"

```
 dfrm <- read.table("C:/dir/fil.dat")  # resist the temptation to use backslashes
 dfrm[2,2]   # would give you the second item on the second row.
```

By default the field separator in R is "white-space" and that seems to be what you have, so you do not need to supply a `sep=` argument and the read.table function will attempt to import as numeric. To be on the safe side, you might consider forcing that option with `colClasses=rep("numeric", 3)` because if it encounters a strange item (such as often produced by Excel dumps), you will get a factor variable and will probably not understand how to recover gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the response and clear explanation. I will look into using read.table now instead.